# Using Directive causes field to be grayed out, but field is still functional

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a directive in order to leverage pickadate.js within my AngularJS app. When I apply the directive to an input field, the field becomes grayed out, but is still functional. How do I get the field to not be grayed out? The directive is functioning as expected.

Here is the input:

```
<input type="text" id="datestart" class="form-control"  pick-a-date="{format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'}" data-ng-model="vm.itemdatestart" placeholder="Start Date">
```

Here is the directive:

```
// Pick a date directive used as pick-a-date on HTML element
appDirectives.directive('pickADate', function() {
    return {
        // Restrict it to be an attribute in this case
        restrict: 'A',
        // responsible for registering DOM listeners as well as updating the DOM
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.pickadate(scope.$eval(attrs.pickADate));
        },
    };
});
```

Comment: check if the directive is adding any class in the DOM

Comment: It does. I had missed that when looking at the DOM before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just put together a little demo to test your situation.

http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/jPOPxE

Looks like the pickadate plugin adds the `readonly` attribute to the input element.

[image]

You could re-style the element with CSS. Here's another demo.

http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/EjxjpX

Comment: That did it. I missed that while inspecting the DOM!